# Формы и их изменения их компонентов

Tags: html, django

Приветствую всех, помогите разобраться как можно изменять и дополнять компоненты форм, я наверное плохо искал.
Вот например есть форма

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    groups = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Group.objects.all())
```

Как указать название которое будет выводиться на страницы?
Как сделать так, что бы при выборе записи происходил запрос, не пойму куда эту строку вставить и как.

```
< select onChange="document.form1.submit();">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выводиться будет `verbose_name` поля модели или свойство `label` самого поля, если оно есть (в качестве метки к полю, в само пле будет выводиться его значение). Запрос при смене делается Ajax'ом.

Answer (score 1):

Вот тебе пример рабочей формы:

```
class GroupForm(ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Group
    exclude = ('owner',)
    widgets = {
        'name':widgets.TextInput({'class': 'fields', 'placeholder': 'Название'}),
        'type':widgets.Select({'class': 'select_field',}),
        'description':widgets.Textarea({'class': 'textareas', 'placeholder': 'Описание'}),
        'logo':widgets.FileInput({'class': 'upload_image'}),
    }
```

В шаблоне можешь написать форму вручную, там свой список и остальные поля тегами типа {{ myform.name }}